# Changing observable value in a component doesn't trigger subscribe in a service

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have a scenario where I send data from a component to a service which then manipulates data. The idea was that when I fetch data in the component that I push the change to a `BehaviorSubject` variable  using `next`.

For some unbeknown to me reason, `this.person.subscribe()` doesn't get triggered when passing the value using `next`. However, when I check if the value in the service was changed I see that it was properly updated.

**Component**

```
  constructor(private incomeService: IncomeService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Fetching data from a service 

    this.person = fetchedTestData;

    // This doesn't trigger subscribe method in the service
    this.incomeService.person.next(fetchedTestData);

    // The data is definitely changed because the value is correctly set
    console.log(this.incomeService.person)
  }
```

**Service**

```
person: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  
constructor() {
    this.person.subscribe(person => {
      // Do something else
    });
  }
```

What seems to be the culprit here?

Comment: Could you add where you're providing this service?

Comment: You're probably using different instances of the service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in a function that was generating an error and that is executed before calling `next`. Unfortunately I missed it because errors in my Google Chrome console were hidden.

So as a reminder for anyone else having a similar problem; check that your methods are running error free before panicking.

Comment: If you solved your problem like so, mark this as the answer.

Comment: @xTheDoctah You have to wait a bit before you are able to mark question as answered. 24 hours I believe.

Comment: Ops, my bad , you're probably right , sorry bout that.

Answer (score 3):

Generally Angular services are meant to handle data retrieval and all business logic, while the components subscribe to Observables for display purposes.

If I understand your situation correctly, you'd be better off doing something like this:

**Service**

```
public person$$ = new BehaviorSubject<unknown>(null);
public person$ = this.person$$.asObservable();

public getPerson(): void {
    // logic for retrieving data
    this.person$$.next(response);
}
```

**Component**

```
public person$ = this.incomeService.person$;

// if you wanted to use console for debugging you could also add
// .pipe(tap(person => console.log(person)))
// which would log to console whenever the person$$ subject is updated in the service

constructor(private incomeService: IncomeService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.incomeService.getPerson();
}
```

**Template**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="person$ | async as person">
{{ person | json }}
</ng-container>
```

In this case, because the `async` pipe is used in the template, it automatically handles the subscription (and unsubscribing when the component is destroyed). You could also `.subscribe` in the component logic, just make sure to have an `unsubscribe` call in there somewhere to prevent memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

In the service you have `person` as a behavior subject. You'd update it there not in your component.

component

```
this.incomeService.updatePerson('something');
```

service

```
constructor() {
    this.person.subscribe(person => {
        console.log(person);
    });
}

updatePerson(arg:string){
    console.log('is this happening?', arg);
    this.person.next(arg);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the result is the same as in my case. For some reason `this.person.subscribe(...)` doesn't get triggered.

Comment: I updated the answer with some debugging ideas.

Comment: That is not what your code shows. See this working example I use to learn and troubleshoot BehaviorSubject. https://stackblitz.com/edit/state-with-service-basic?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsearch.service.ts